# Boxplot for list in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the foll. dataframe:

```
    Month(s)                                             Vals
0        Mar                             [3.691756, 3.59027575]
1  Mar - Apr  [4.75706325, 3.138456625, 1.90741175, 3.019323]
2  Mar - May  [4.698454875, 3.317812375, 2.512695375, 2.8096]
3  Mar - Jun  [4.70111125, 3.474370375, 2.53445075, 2.926820]
4  Mar - Jul  [4.79324375, 3.56983175, 2.39309125, 3.0682476]
5  Mar - Aug  [4.618898125, 3.613308875, 2.361248375, 3.0536]
```

I want to create a boxplot with x-axis using 'Month(s)' column and y-axis using the 'Vals' column. Simply doing `df.plot()` does not work. How do I fix it?

Comment: You do realize your `Vals` column is a `list`, right? You will need to either explode it into different columns, and then plot, or you will need to collapse the list into some statistical measures (such as mean and variance) that you can plot. Your question does not have enough information for me to figure out which approach fits your needs. Also, your `Month(s)` column needs to be unitary value for the plot to make sense. Further, change `Month(s)` to something else, because that name is asking for trouble.

Comment: thanks @Kartik, I want to draw a boxplot so not sure if computing a statistical measure helps.

Comment: Ok, explain you data in `Vals` then... Box plots are used to visualize the distribution of a data, they are like a normal distribution as seen from above. They have a line for the average, and the box bounds representing standard deviation, and then tails representing the confidence intervals, and dots beyond that showing the outliers. Your `Vals` does not conform to any of those measures right now.

Answer (score 2):

Preparing your DataFrame by setting "Month(s)" as index

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('      Mar',[3.691756, 3.59027575]),
               ('Mar - Apr', [4.75706325, 3.138456625, 1.90741175, 3.019323]),
               ('Mar - May',[4.698454875, 3.317812375, 2.512695375, 2.8096]),
               ('Mar - Jun', [4.70111125, 3.474370375, 2.53445075, 2.926820]),
               ('Mar - Jul', [4.79324375, 3.56983175, 2.39309125, 3.0682476]),
               ('Mar - Aug', [4.618898125, 3.613308875, 2.361248375, 3.0536])],
              columns=['Month(s)','Vals']).set_index('Month(s)')
```

will enable you to convert each row to a Series

```
df['Vals'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x)).T.boxplot(figsize=(10,10),rot=45)
```

[image: Plot Output]