# Box plot of a pd.Series with list of DateTimeIndexed arrays

Tags: python, pandas, series, boxplot

I am trying to make a box plot of values contained in a `Series`. I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507404/time-series-boxplot-in-pandas) but my case is a little different. My Series values is a list of N D-dimensional arrays taken on each day. What I want is to make a per day plot where a box plot is drawn for each of the N arrays but I am getting, `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`. Any ideas please?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT1:** 
Data sample:

```
Date
2014-02-01    [-0.13934771706335308, 0.52431438441752, 0.303... -> Box plot 1
2014-02-02    [-0.15212360891411472, 0.5057162101551876, 0.3... -> Box plot 2
2014-02-03    [-0.15906372162522756, 0.4900703653941794, 0.2...
2014-02-04    [-0.18159376988693987, 0.48163379794842914, 0....
2014-02-05    [-0.18234763860841446, 0.4768498811155851, 0.2...
```

Sample Series data:

```
N= 200
D=20
ts = pd.Series([np.random.randn(D) for _ in range(N)], index=pd.date_range(start="2014-02-01", periods=N, freq="D"))
```

**EDIT2:** 
I think I got it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066648/boxplot-for-list-in-pandas-dataframe) `ts.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x)).T.boxplot(figsize=(10, 10), rot=90)` but the output is dense especially when N is large. I am trying to sample it either by taking the sum, mean or the last of values in a range of 3 Business (B) day but keeps me in trouble. Any help is highly appreciated. Code sample I am trying with:

```
ts.resample('3D', label='right', closed='right', how='last').apply(lambda x: x.last()).T.boxplot(figsize=(20, 10), rot=90)
```

returns: `Must Produce Aggregated Value`

**EDIT3:** 
I think I got the results I want with

```
tss=ts.resample('2D', label='right', closed='right').agg(lambda x: x.sum())
```

Comment: Show your code and a sample of the data

Comment: @SreeramTP thanks for the response. What is have tries is based on the reference post by I can not find a way (an elegant way) to adapt it. Excuse my ignorance I am new in dataframes rationale.

Comment: I have problem running `agg(lambda x: x.median())`, returns `TypeError: setting an array element with a sequence.`. Any ideas how can we make it to compute the median instead of the sum?